# Determining the cheapest way to buy n products online

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I'm currently working on a simple script for personal use which would take a list of all the items I want to buy and the prices of each item from price comparators online and try to find the cheapest way to buy all of them (keeping in mind that if you buy mulptiple items from the same store, you're only going to pay the shipping cost once). What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

I thought about using Hungarian algorithm for this but realized this may not be the best idea as buying from the same store is often precisely what we *do* want, not something to avoid. Trying to greedily find the stores with the most items at hand, on the other hand, also falls short cause the fact that they do sell them does not mean they sell them at the best price, even if we only pay the shipping costs once.

What would you recommend? Is there some easily implementable solution to this?

Comment: First thought be to start with a feasible solution that minimizes the number of different stores (i.e. buy as many products from a single store as possible), then for each product see if buying it from another store will lower the total (meaning the difference in price should offset the increased shipping cost, unless you already had an item assigned to that store).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a hard problem to solve exactly, because if you could solve this exactly you could take problems from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem and set up costs so that the exact solution to your problem would a solution of the set cover problem. Possibly some of the approximate solutions given in that article, or elsewhere, would help. The easiest way to throw high technology at it might be to find an integer linear programming package and use that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but rather a clarification on your problem. Since it's too long to fit into a comment, I post it here.

Let there be `M` shops and `N` items. A matrix `A` is given, where `A(i, j)` is the price of buying item `j` from shop `i` (we set `A(i, j)` to infinity if shop `i` doesn't sell item `j`). Also given is an array `S`, where `S(i)` is the shipping cost of shop `i`.

**Problem**: find the function `b:{1,...,N} -> {1,...,M}`, meaning buying item `j` from shop `b(j)`, which minimizes the total cost.

Already you can see that this is different from the setting of Hungarian algorithm, the latter asking for a minimizing PERMUTATION of `{1,...,N}`.

At this point, there are several questions about the nature of the inputs:

- what are the ranges of `M` and `N`? If either of them are very small (e.g. < 20), an exponential algorithm might be acceptable.
- is the matrix `A` sparse (i.e. most items can only be bought in few shops) or dense (i.e. most items are available in most shops)?